# In XML Schema, how to define an element which can have a text node and one which cannot

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XML snippet and corresponding XML Schema:

```
<authors>
  <author>
    <keyname>Foo</keyname>
    <forenames>Bar</forenames>
  </author>
</authors>
```

Schema:

```
<element name="authors"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="arXiv:authorsType"/>

<complexType name="authorsType">
  <sequence>
    <element name="author" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="arXiv:authorType"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="authorType">
  <sequence>
    <element name="keyname" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="string"/>
    <element name="forenames" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="string"/>
    <element name="suffix" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="string"/>
    <element name="affiliation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="string"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
```

But I am curious how would the schema look like to allow this:

```
<authors>
  Text.
  <author>
    <keyname>Foo</keyname>
    <forenames>Bar</forenames>
  </author>
</authors>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A node containing elements and text node is a node with *[mixed content](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content)*. You can declare that using the `mixed` attribute in `complexType`:

```
<complexType name="authorsType" mixed="true">
    <sequence>
        <element name="author" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="arXiv:authorType"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Now `authorsType` accepts elements and text nodes containing character content.

See also: [XSD Spec - Mixed content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-0-20010502/#mixedContent)

Comment: Thanks! So `mixed` nodes are the only ones which can be like that?

Comment: That's the definition of mixed content. See the first link above which points to the definition in the XML Specification.